# Not able to run this applet code in browser

Tags: java, applet, awt

In my Java course, I am learning applet. And I have to do it with `awt`. In order to run the applet, I first have written the code below and compiled it to get `MyApplet.class` file and also have placed the `RunApplet.html` file in the same directory of `MyApplet.class` file.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyApplet extends Applet{
    public int x,y,w,h;
    public void init(){
        x=Integer.parseInt(getParameter("xValue"));
        y=Integer.parseInt(getParameter("yValue"));
        w=Integer.parseInt(getParameter("wValue"));
        h=Integer.parseInt(getParameter("hValue"));
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawRect(x,y,w,h);
    }

}
```

and the `RunApplet.html` file is:

```html
<html>
<body>
<applet code="MyApplet.class" width="150" hight="100">
    <param name = "xValue" value = "20">
    <param name = "yValue" value = "40">
    <param name = "wValue" value = "100">
    <param name = "hValue" value = "50">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

But, when I am running the `html` file with a browser, it's neither showing any applet nor any error message. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Try setting the color before calling `drawRect()`. You might be drawing a white rectangle on a white background, or something similar.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). 3) Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  ..

Comment: .. If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again. 4) `hight="100"` should be `height="100"` When having problems with applets, always make sure to validate the HTML.